# lseek with 2 gb file in windows

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about file seeking position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686434/question-about-file-seeking-position)

I am facing one problem related to lseek(). It returns failure in case when we are trying to access 2GB+ file in windows (32 bit machine). Is there any limit upto which lseek can set the file pointer in the file which we are using???
offset valye is 2154654555.

Compiler Details

c:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Compil32.exe

Comment: The limitation is that `long` isn't really wide enough to hold the file size.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at _lseeki64, which takes 64-bit offsets. lseek() (and its successor, _lseek()) are limited to signed 32-bit offsets, which have an upper limit of 2147483647. Your offset of 215465455 exceeds that (and would be treated as a negative number if stored in a long). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yee101t. (You'll need something comparable for your compiler.)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value of off_t is 2147483647, where off_t is the the type for the offset in lseek()

Answer (score 1):

lseek doesn't work with files greater than 2 GB, because the offset input is on a 32 bit variable which cannot take value greater than 2147483647. In many OS it is either supported through compile time macros or by providing alternative functions.

You can try [_lseeki64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa298446%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) in case of MSVC Compiler. It takes 64 bit variable for offset. Since you are not using MSVC, you can check for equivalent function.